# roscpp failure to call service written in rospy

Tags: rospy, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it ok to write a Ros node in cpp to call a ros service written in python?
I'm able to use "rosservice call /service" to do that, but using cpp to call the same service just didn't work. Just want to know is it some problem with my code or just simply cannot call rospy service in roscpp.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49733/roscpp-failure-to-call-service-written-in-rospy/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2012-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's almost certainly a problem with your code.

Please update your question with the relevant portions of your program.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2012-12-05**:
thanks, i'll look into my code. i'll update the question if i can't solve it.